# In latest eclipse version, I imported a project and this happened:

Tags: java, eclipse

When I Imported an old, non-Eclipse project into Eclipse, [an old Minecraft mod, to be exact], (Yes, I added Metadata, classpath, project)

It gave these errors for almost Every Single Class File:

```
Source Not Found:
There is no source file attached to the class file IEnergyHandler.class

// Compiled from (classfile).java (version 1.6 : 50.0, no super bit)
public abstract interface _jx.PumpkinAPI.IEnergyHandler {

  // Method descriptor #7 (Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;)I
  public abstract int getEnergyAmount(net.minecraft.item.ItemStack arg0);

  // Method descriptor #7 (Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;)I
  public abstract int getConsumeEnergyAmount(net.minecraft.item.ItemStack arg0);

  // Method descriptor #10 (Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;)Z
  public abstract boolean isEnergyStackItem(net.minecraft.item.ItemStack arg0);

  // Method descriptor #10 (Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;)Z
  public abstract boolean isResourceItem(net.minecraft.item.ItemStack arg0);

  // Method descriptor #13 (Lnet/minecraft/world/World;IIILnet/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer;Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;)Z
  public abstract boolean onConsumeResourceEvent(net.minecraft.world.World arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer arg4, net.minecraft.item.ItemStack arg5);

  // Method descriptor #15 (Lnet/minecraft/world/World;IIILnet/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer;Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;Z)Z
  public abstract boolean onPutEvent(net.minecraft.world.World arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer arg4, net.minecraft.item.ItemStack arg5, boolean arg6);
}
```

The Rest of the class files have a different error that STILL says

> Source Not Found: There is no source file attached to the class file
>   (Classfile).class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do: if your "project" does not contain **source** code, then it is not a **project**.

You could treat it as library, that you might reference to from other projects.

The only other alternative is to use a java decompiler, to manually turn .class into .java and to then add those source files to a new project.

Or, according to your comment: simply don't "import" as project. Create a new project; define a source folder, and pull in the java source files.

Comment: Well... Here's the thing: It is a past project that is very Old which was created on a seperate platform. I have no idea why this is happening, it has source code but it is not from eclipse.